# AFNetworking request operations - creating a Funnel/Bottle-neck queue singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, nsoperation

**Setup**

I have two areas in my program - `branch 1` and `branch 2` - where network requests are made asynchronously 1 concurrent GET request at a time for each area. Requests are sent 1 at a time because the server has a tiny few milliseconds of a grace period for any user making requests to the server. Running 1 concurrent request at a time aims to aid that grace period.

The operation has been made such that if any request fails in any branch - there is a fail safe to just repeat the request again.

**Problem:**

When I run these branches separately from each other, i.e. not at the same time, the server is happy. However, as soon as I allow for both operations to take place at the same time the server throws a `429` error which is the error letting the user know that `there are too many requests coming in at any one time`. What then happens is that half of the requests fails, and then because of the fail safe the requests are being sent again for processing until they're all completed.
It's a waste of time and resources on behalf of the user's data package.

**Scenario**

`Branch 1` sends out 10 requests (normally its within the thousands, processing one at a time, but for simplicity purposes we'll keep it at 10).
These 10 requests will be processed concurrently 1 at a time very quickly and return with their appropriate data objects.

Now if we run `branch 1` operation again - 10 requests concurrently and then add `branch 2's` 10 requests, this will create 20 request operations - twice as many - GOING OUT to the server which will cause roughly half of the requests from both branch 1 and 2 to fail, with the fail-safe then kicking in to resend those request operations. boohoo.

**Question**

Is there a way to funnel these request operations coming out of my application regardless of where these two branches lay within my app so that we can control and bottleneck the request operations going out to the server so that the server won't be bombarded with requests only for half of the requests to fail?

**Possible solution**

One idea I had was to create a singleton that would act as a queue as well as the bottle neck required that would allow me to add request operations from ANY branch anywhere within my code base - hence why i thought a singleton would be a great idea for this - and then as soon as it realises a request operation has been added to the queue to then to have that queue run 1 concurrent request at at time.

This I think will work great for my purposes, I just didn't know how to handle the completion blocks of the requests since the request operation from `Branch 1` are different from the completion blocks of the request operations from `Branch 2`.

How would you manage that? Is there anything we can do?

---

**Edit 1 - What I'm currently doing**

**In Branch 1 - Using AFHTTPOperation:**

1) For each process I create a for loop that iterates 10 times adding 10 `AFHTTPRequestOperation`s to a local array called multipleOperations of type `NSMutableArray`.

2) I then add the multipleOperations array to a batchOfRequestOperations method like so:

```
NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:muiltipleOperations
                       progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations){
//Do some stuff here for each iteration
} 
completionBlock:^(NSArray*operations){
//Call the method that repeats this process again.
}];
```

3) I then add the operations to the mainQueue like so

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

I'm now wondering whether this process in branch one even has it set to 1 concurrenncy, cant see that it is :\

**In Branch 2 using NSURLSessionDataTask (just realised, wouldnt it be easier if they were all using the same subclass? lol**

I notice that I am using a `AFHTTPSessionManager` that creates `NSURLSessionDataTasks`.. which doesnt run in a for loop but instead calls its own method for another request to be sent out EVERY TIME the request executes its own completion block. So it will forever keep calling itself as soon as the previous request in branch 2 is done. This is how I know its running only 1 request at a time concurrently. So thats good.

Is there anyway to make this more cleaner?

No where am I using `HTTPRequestOperationManager` :( Can someone show me how things can be done properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're using `AFNetworking`, can't you just set the underlying `NSOperationQueue` of `AFHttpRequestOperationManager` to have a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1`? That way it'll only ever send one request at a time, regardless of which branch its coming from (well, assuming you're using the `[AFHttpRequestOperationManager manager]` singleton). `[[AFHttpRequestOperationManager manager] operationQueue].maxConcurrentOperationQueue = 1;`

Comment: Yes but then when you run those branches together at the same time they dont know the other is running, so they both will be sending two - 1 concurrent operations - at the same time and this causes half of the requests to fail since the server is happy in receiving the rate of requests coming from one branch.

Thats why I presented the scenario as is to see if theres a way for all my request operations no matter which branch its coming from to ALL line up in ONE queue and to then have that final queue run 1 concurrent operation but to then also be able to handle the completion block too

Comment: Are you using a different `AFHttpRequestOperationManager` for each branch then?

Comment: I've added more information in the post.  Please look at **Edit 1**. I have some more helpful information which I think will help answer some of your questions. In short I am not using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManagers` only `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and a `AFHTTPSessionManager`. I'm starting to think that my implementation isn't ideal.

Comment: ahahaha @MikeS, I just read your profile and loved the bit where it reads that `you love to solve asynchronous / concurrency` and that you think you `might be crazy or something` because of it! Seems to me youre the man for the problem Mike! Pleasure to have you on board man.

Comment: Anyone there who could give me a solid idea on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, I can see a some things you'll probably want to change. First off, yes, it will be *much* easier if you use either `AFHTTPOperation`s or `NSURLSessionDataTask`s, but not both.

If you're going to use `AFHTTPOperation`, then don't queue the operations on `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`. The reason being is that that is the main UI queue and you don't want your network operations blocking it. What you should be doing is creating your own `NSOperationQueue` and setting its concurrency to 1.

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

Using your idea of a singleton to store that queue somewhere you can access from anywhere in your app would be a good way to go about making sure you send all your network operations through the same queue.

That being said, **I'd recommend using `NSURLSessionDataTask` with `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead**. The docs for AFNetworking state:

> Developers targeting iOS 7 or Mac OS X 10.9 or later that deal
>   extensively with a web service are encouraged to subclass
>   AFHTTPSessionManager, providing a class method that returns a shared
>   singleton object on which authentication and other configuration can
>   be shared across the application.

That sounds like a good way to accomplish what you want. Basically you'll create a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` with a class method that creates an instance initialized with a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. You can configure the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` however is appropriate for your app, but the main property you'll be interested in for this particular issue is [`HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost):

> This property determines the maximum number of simultaneous
>   connections made to each host by tasks within sessions based on this
>   configuration.

With that set to `1`, you can let `AFHTTPSessionManager` (well, actually, `NSURLSession`) worry about making sure that only one request is made to your server at any given time.

Something along these lines:

```
@interface AppHTTPSessionManager : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (instancetype)appSession;

@end

@implementation AppHTTPSessionManager

+ (instancetype)appSession {
    static AppHTTPSessionManager *_appSession = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
        _appSession = [[AppHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    });
    return _appSession;
}

@end
```

Then, whenever you want to make a network call, make sure you create your `NSURLSessionDataTask` from `[AppHTTPSessionManager appSession]`. If you do, those tasks should automatically be limited to one request to the server at a time.

Comment: Thanky you for getting back to me. I ended up using AFHTTPOperationManager and using its `queue` property where I attach all operations to that sharedManager's queue set at a concurrency of 1. I think it will do the trick. But mike you've suggested using `AFHTTPSessionManager`, I believe theres an issue with attaching these to queues right? Session Manager was not made for operations etc.. correct me if I'm wrong, I read it somewhere. Could you shed some light? I need to queue hundreds of requests and adding for everything to work on my end, with plenty of callbacks.

Comment: Options 1 and 4 in the answer you linked to are pretty much the same as what I suggested in this answer, and either will work fine. The main reason I recommended using `AFHTTPSessionManager` is that it's using newer APIs from Apple that give you finer grained control over some things and give you better support for background network tasks, etc. There's really no reason that tasks created from `AFHTTPSessionManager` can't be used in an `NSOperationQueue`, there just isn't a built-in way to do it so you'd have to write your own `NSOperation` wrapper (option 2 in the answer you linked to).

Comment: Everything is a trade off. If you don't need the extra bits that `AFHTTPSessionManager` and `NSURLSession` give you, and `AFHTTPOperationManager` does exactly what you need then, by all means, use it :)